# How to use ngram analyzer with multi_match

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ngram_analyzer

```
  "analysis": {
    "tokenizer": {
      "ngram_tokenizer": {
        "type": "ngram",
        "min_gram": 2,
        "max_gram": 10,
        "token_chars": []
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "ngram_analyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

And trying to search all fields:

```
  "query": {
   "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "jan teach",
      "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer", 
      "operator":   "and",
      "type":       "cross_fields",
      "fields":     [ "name", "occupation", "surname", ... ]
    }
  }
```

This unfortunalty does not return any results...

Would like this to match to name = "Jane", occupation = "teacher"

Or are there better ways to accomplish this?

Comment: I get the error: "The difference between max_gram and min_gram in NGram Tokenizer must be less than or equal to: [1] but was [8]. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_ngram_diff] index level setting." when running this on es v7.6.2, maybe that is the root?

Comment: analyzer works even with this error. You might need to set setting index.max_ngram_diff to 10

Comment: How are you analyzing the fields `name` and `occupation` at index time? Are they getting the `ngram_analyzer`?

Comment: Not analyzing at index time. Doing it while searching

Comment: You need to analyze those fields at index time with the `ngram_analyzer`, if you aren't being explicit in "properties" the are processs as `keyword` and `text` (standard analyzer) so there is no toke "jan" that can be matched. FWIW `cross_fields` combines fields together only if they share the same analyzer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is what you need is [edge_ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) not ngram tokenizer(costly in terms of index space as it creates more tokens) as you are doing prefix search of tokens(Jan in Jane and tech in teacher).

Second, using search time, you should use the Standard analyzer as a [search time analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) as tokens(jan and teacher) is already present.

Working example:

**Index Def**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "edgengram_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase"
                        ],
                        "tokenizer": "edgeNGramTokenizer"
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer": {
                    "edgeNGramTokenizer": {
                        "token_chars": [
                            "letter",
                            "digit"
                        ],
                        "min_gram": "2",
                        "type": "edgeNGram",
                        "max_gram": "10"
                    }
                }
            },
            "max_ngram_diff": "10"
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer" : "edgengram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer" : "standard"
            },
            "occupation" :{
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "edgengram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer" : "standard"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index Sample doc**

```
{
    "name" : "Jane",
    "occupation" : "teacher"
}
```

**Generated tokens for `Jane`**

```
POST yourindexname/_analyze

{
    "text" : "Jane",
    "analyzer": "edgengram_analyzer"
}

    {
        "tokens": [
            {
                "token": "ja",
                "start_offset": 0,
                "end_offset": 2,
                "type": "word",
                "position": 0
            },
            {
                "token": "jan",
                "start_offset": 0,
                "end_offset": 3,
                "type": "word",
                "position": 1
            },
            {
                "token": "jane",
                "start_offset": 0,
                "end_offset": 4,
                "type": "word",
                "position": 2
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Search query same as yours(but without analyzer)**

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "jane teach",
            "operator": "and",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "fields": [
                "name",
                "occupation"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "ngram",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.5753642,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Jane",
                    "occupation": "teacher"
                }
            }
        ]
```